# How to collect data from server to LibreOffice Calc

Tags: pi-3, data-transfer, database, mqtt, nodered

I have Mosquitto and Node-Red installed on my Pi 3. I want to be able to log the data into a spreadsheet of some sort. Is there a way to do this with Calc or a spreadsheet of some sort on the Pi? The complete project is wireless but no access to the internet (hope that's of some use and/or makes sense).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All depends on what you want to do with the data,    you can log data to a CSV file and import that into a spreadsheet program,    Should include what type of data you currently have, and what you want to end up with. If you just want to store and search data, mysql is a good option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to store DHT temp and humidiy data plus soil moisture readings. I have an Arduino Mega in my garden publishing the data over wifi to my Pi 3 running Mosquitto and Node-Red in my house. I would like to save that data to be able to look back at different time and dates to compare changes.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mosquitto or Node-red, but what form is the data in on the pi side?

Comment: I apologize, I’m not sure what you are asking me.

Comment: The data is being sent to the pi,  is it being stored anywhere? Or just displayed

Comment: It is published to the MQTT server and displayed on the Node Red webpage. In my log through my terminal it is only stored for so long.

Comment: Also I’d like to add that I have MySQL installed but don’t know much about it.

Comment: Here is a thread on exporting Node Red to CSV,   then you can import CSV to Spreadsheet of your choice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099128/node-red-function-and-export-to-csv/43099423#43099423